# Jenkins multibranch pipeline that creates multiple jobs with shared libraries

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have an environment with multibranch pipeline and shared libraries.
Scanning and creating jobs is working like the following example:

JenkinsFile:

```
deployKubernetes()
```

I am trying to create 2 different jobs from shared libraries the same JenkinsFile and it doesn't work:

```
deployKubernetes()
deployDashboard()
```

Is this possible in some way?

Trying to avoid adding second JenkinsFile since we have quota issue with Bitbucket API.